# Что именно разработчики .NET 4.6.2 изменили в SslStream помимо SSL3?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tls

**Описание проблемы:** пользователи поголовно начали жаловаться на странное поведение программы (которая была написана на .NET 4.5) после автоматического обновления Windows. Начал разбираться, тестировать. Воспроизвел проблему у себя на .NET 4.6.2. Оказывается транспорт `SslStream` начиная с .NET 4.6 поменял свое поведение. Причем непонятно в каком месте.

Взял сторонний транспорт (Chilkat), сравнил - везде получается одинаковые параметры, TLS 1.0, Cipher - Aes128, Hash - Sha1, одинаковые байты идущие через соединение...

Но! - Chilkat отрабатывает нормально, а `SslStream` рвет соединение на `ReadAsync` с исключением: `IOException, сбой операции дешифрования`. Журналы ошибок Windows пустые.

**Вопрос:** что конкретно изменилось в реализации?

p.s. `Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto=true` в `appconfig` не помогает, поведение не меняется.

---

**Update:**

Посмотрел локальные исключения, вот что всплыло: `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Не удается установить связь с локальной системой безопасности.` Погуглил, нашел что это связано с лицензией на Windows. Хоть убейте не понимаю чем связана неактивированная тестовая Windows с работоспособностью `SslStream`. Клиентов ведь не заставишь поголовно покупать лицензии...

**Часть синхронного стека вызовов:**

```
System.dll!System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessReadErrorCode(System.Net.SecurityStatus errorCode = {неизвестно}, byte[] buffer = {неизвестно}, int offset = {неизвестно}, int count = {неизвестно}, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest = {неизвестно}, byte[] extraBuffer = {неизвестно})
    System.dll!System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessFrameBody(int readBytes = {неизвестно}, byte[] buffer = {неизвестно}, int offset = {неизвестно}, int count = {неизвестно}, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest = {неизвестно})
    System.dll!System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(byte[] buffer = {неизвестно}, int offset = {неизвестно}, int count = {неизвестно}, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest = {неизвестно})
    System.dll!System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(byte[] buffer = {неизвестно}, int offset = {неизвестно}, int count = {неизвестно}, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest = {неизвестно})
    System.dll!System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(byte[] buffer = {неизвестно}, int offset = {неизвестно}, int count = {неизвестно}, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest = {неизвестно})
    System.dll!System.Net.Security._SslStream.Read(byte[] buffer = {неизвестно}, int offset = {неизвестно}, int count = {неизвестно})
>   Application.exe!<Receive>d__a.MoveNext()
```

---

**Update2:**

Провел ряд тестов в процессе воспроизведения проблемы для публичного обозрения - по предварительным данным виноват `Cipher = Aes128`, тот же `Aes256` - работает нормально.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47708/discussion-on-question-by-alexis----net-4-6-2---s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для `.NET 4.+` и `x64` разрядных ОС, глобальный вариант:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchSendAuxRecord"=dword:00000000

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchSendAuxRecord"=dword:00000000
```

Для `.NET 2.+` и `x64` разрядных ОС, глобальный вариант:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SchSendAuxRecord"=dword:00000000

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SchSendAuxRecord"=dword:00000000
```

Действует сразу, перезапуск ОС не требуется.

**Использовать только в крайнем случае!!! Выключение этой структуры связано с большими рисками по отношению к старым версиям SSL\TLS транспорта ОС.**